# Compiler cannot evaluate type arguments in LINQ query

Tags: c#, linq

I have some trouble with a LINQ query that is supposed to group a list by month and year of a date and then sort the sub groups by date. The compiler tells me it cannot evaluate the type arguments and I am terribly confused with all the IGrouping, IOrderedEnumerable, IEnumerable stuff that I can't evaluate them neither...

The problem occurs in the `groupedList.OrderBy(...)` line.

```
public IOrderedEnumerable<IGrouping<String, Asset>> DateAssetList
{
    get
    {
        return AssetManager.Instance.AllAssets.
            GroupBy(asset => ConverterHelper.GetMonthNameByIndex(asset.EntryDate.Month) + " " + asset.EntryDate.Year).
            Select(groupedList => groupedList.OrderBy(asset => asset.EntryDate, new DateComparer())).
            OrderBy(group => group.Key, new DateComparer());
    }
}
```

`AllAssets` is a list of type `Asset`.

`EntryDate` is of type `DateTime`.

The first `GroupBy` statement basically groups all assets by month and year (e.g. march 2015). And now my task is to sort all assets in the subgroup march 2015 but I am not able to get the query working.

Can somebody solve this riddle for me?

EDIT: Added DateComparer class

```
public class DateComparer : IComparer<String>
{
    public int Compare(string x, string y)
    {
        if (DateTime.Parse(x) > DateTime.Parse(y))
            return -1;

        if (DateTime.Parse(x) < DateTime.Parse(y))
            return 1;

        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Compiler cannot evaluate type arguments in the `Select(..)` line at the `groupedList.OrderBy(...)` statement. He wants me to specify them explicitly and I am not able to do that.

Comment: What are you expecting to return (in your own words,not the technical description).  As it stands, you are returning a collections of groups.

Comment: I want to perform a query that returns the type `IOrderedEnumerable<IGrouping<String, Asset>>` so that my listview will display the items in ordered groups with ordered subgroups :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your DataComparer is NOT a comparer of datetimes but a comparer of strings, you said your EntryDate is already a DateTime, so it makes no sense to use a comparer of strings to compare datetimes, basically you just need to remove the second parameter

In all cases that comparer doesn't seem to be of any use and would better be deleted as it doesn't add any comparison logic, it's no better than just doing the parse inline when you need it (and here you don't need it) than passing in a comparer that conveys the message that "we're doing some custom comparison"

Comment: You are right, this was sort of brainless by me...Query is still not working but I got the error fixed I asked for :)